# How to use PATCH method with CL_REST_HTTP_CLIENT?

Tags: rest, web-services, abap

I am trying to consume an external REST service. Example:

```
DATA : lo_client TYPE REF TO if_http_client.

cl_http_client=>create_by_url(
  EXPORTING
    url                = 'http://my_url'
  IMPORTING
    client             = lo_client
  EXCEPTIONS
    argument_not_found = 1
    plugin_not_active  = 2
    internal_error     = 3
    OTHERS             = 4 ).

DATA(rest_client) = NEW CL_REST_HTTP_CLIENT( lo_client ).

rest_client->GET( ).
```

GET, POST, PUT and DELETE are Ok since they are implemented in the class `CL_REST_HTTP_CLIENT`.

[image: methods supported]

Did anyone find a solution to use the PATCH method or how could I consume it otherwise?

PS: the constant for PATCH exists (`if_rest_message=>gc_method_patch`), but as I said, it's not implemented (send_receive).

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CL_HTTP_CLIENT to set method freely, CL_REST_HTTP_CLIENT is also using this class under the hood.

```
DATA : lo_client TYPE REF TO if_http_client.

cl_http_client=>create_by_url(
  EXPORTING
    url                = 'http://my_url'
  IMPORTING
    client             = lo_client
  EXCEPTIONS
    argument_not_found = 1
    plugin_not_active  = 2
    internal_error     = 3
    OTHERS             = 4 ).

lo_client->request->set_method( 'PATCH' ).
lo_client->request->set_content_type( 'application/json' ).

lo_client->send( ).

lo_client->receive(
  EXCEPTIONS
    http_communication_failure = 1
    http_invalid_state         = 2
    http_processing_failed     = 3
    OTHERS                     = 4 ).
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported indeed. Quick and dirty way to get it to work is to copy the class and add the following method:

```
method PATCH.
  send_receive( iv_http_method = if_rest_message=>gc_method_patch io_entity = io_entity ).
endmethod.
```